# Multiple IP addresse PING

Tags: python

The below code works perfectly if the input file ip_file.txt have the following format.

```
8.8.8.8
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.microsoft.com
```

But how can I ping the IPs if the input is something like this and write the output same in format.

```
8.8.8.8, www.google.com
www.yahoo.com,www.microsoft.com
```

My code is given below:

```
import subprocess
import threading
import time
import re

timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")
timesec = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")

raw_list = []
def ping(host):
    results_file = open("results_bng_" + str(timestr) + ".txt", "a")
    p = subprocess.Popen(["ping", host, "-n", "5"], shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    response = p.communicate()[0]
    for i in response.split("\n"):
            para =i.split("=")
            # print(para)
            try:
                if para[0].strip() =="Minimum":
                    latency =para[3].strip()
                    print(latency)
                    latfin = re.findall('\d+', latency)
                    latfin1 = latfin[0]
            except:
                print("time run")

    if "Received = 1" and "Approximate" in response:
        print(f"UP {host} Ping Successful")
        results_file.write(f"{host},UP,{latfin1},{timesec}"+ "\n")
    else:
        print(f"Down {host} Ping Unsuccessful")
        results_file.write(f"{host},Down,0,{timesec}" + "\n")
    results_file.close()

with open(r'bng.txt', "r") as server_list_file:
    hosts = server_list_file.read()
    hosts_list =hosts.split('\n')
num_threads = 1
number = 0
while number< len(hosts_list):
    # print(number)
    for i in range(num_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=ping, args=(hosts_list[number+i],))
        t.start()
    t.join()
    number = number +1
```

Comment: A faster and more pythonic alternative is using the `socket` library

Comment: @XxJames07- But there is no support for the ICMP ping in the `socket` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace each `newline` character with a `comma` and split at each `comma`:

bng.txt:

```
8.8.8.8, www.google.com
www.yahoo.com,www.microsoft.com
```

Code:

```
with open(r'bng.txt', "r") as server_list_file:
    hosts = server_list_file.read()
    hosts_list = hosts.replace('\n', ',').split(',')

for host in hosts_list:
    print(host.strip())  # strip remaining whitespaces
```

Out:

```
8.8.8.8
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.microsoft.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Pings are specific IP packets that can only be sent to one ip at a time. There are special IP which are meant for broadcasting. For example, you could direct your ping at a specific subnet and the devices connected to that subnet could all choose to answer to a ping. Note that most routers or IP stacks do not answer to such broadcast pings nowadays as they could be used to discover the devices that are connected to the subnet.

Answer (score 0):

After you open your file you need to do a for loop and read each line at a time and split based on comma. That will ultimately give you a list of all single IPs / hosts to ping. Something like.

```
listOfAllIPs = []
for line in file:
     x = line.split(',') ## this makes x a list
     listOfAllIPs = listOfAllIPs + x
```

After that runs you should be able to use listOfAllIPs as your input. It will have 1 IP or host per item. Just iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

this will be useful for you

```
import os
import subprocess

list = []
with open('./ip.txt', 'r') as f:
    ip = f.read().split(',')
    list.append(ip)

for i in range(len(list[0])):
    ip = list[0][i]
    print(30*'-') 
    if subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", ip], shell=True).wait() == 1: print('active', ip)
    else: print('inactive', ip)
```